# Linking storyboard view controller to its own viewcontroller.swift in Xcode 7.2

Tags: xcode, swift, ios9

In the new Xcode 7.2 (iOS9), how do I add a viewcontroller.swift file and link it to a manually added view controller in the storyboard?

(This seems to be different than previous versions of Xcode where one would manually add a Cocoa Touch file after dragging a new view controller object in thestoryboard.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It has always been the same for me but here are the steps that I follow.

1. Right click the file explorer on the left
2. Click Source->Next->Subclass `UIViewController`
3. Drag `UIViewController` into `Interface Builder`
4. Click the yellow circle to focus on the `UIViewController`
5. Click the `Identity Inspector`
6. Set the `Custom Class` to the name in your `Swift` File

Comment: @user5696752 No problem. Please accept the answer to help others find it faster.